# adding optional parameters in paths dynamically ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, rails-routing

I have routes like this:

```
resources :lesson_plans do
   resources :videos
end
```

and also

```
resources :subjects do
  resources :lesson_plans do
  resources :videos
 end
end
```

Now I want to create dynamic paths and adding conditional parameters to them.

If I have url like:

```
http://localhost:3000/teacher/katherine-fleming/subjects/3/lesson_plans/3
```

the path is now:

```
http://localhost:3000/teacher/katherine-fleming/subjects/3/lesson_plans
/3/videos/new
```

but if I have url like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/teacher/carmel-cynthia/lesson_plans/68
```

the path is:

```
http://localhost:3000/teacher/carmel-cynthia/lesson_plans//videos/new.68
```

but it should be as its my requirement:

```
http://localhost:3000/teacher/carmel-cynthia/lesson_plans/68/videos/new
```

the code I am trying is:

**Code:**

```
<% subject_path = params[:subject_id].present? ? 'subject_' : '' %>
<% subject_var = params[:subject_id].present? ? @subject : '' %>
```

**Button:**

```
<%= link_to '+ New Video', send("new_teacher_teacher_#
{subject_path}lesson_plan_video_path", @teacher, subject_var, @lesson_plan),
 remote: true, class: "btn btn-info plans-items-btn" %>
```

Any more better way to cope with it. basically subject_id is what I have optional for both cases.

Comment: `get 'teacher/:teacher_id(/:subjects(/:subject_id))/lesson_plans/:lesson_plan_id' =>  'videos#new'` - What about having something like this at the top of your `routes.rb` ?

Comment: I tried `get 'teacher/:teacher_id(/:subjects(/:subject_id))/lesson_plans/‌​:lesson_plan_id' => 'videos#new'
  post 'teacher/:teacher_id(/:subjects(/:subject_id))/lesson_plans/‌​:lesson_plan_id' => 'lesson_plans#show'` and it says: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/teacher/carmel-cynthia/lesson_plans/68"):`

Comment: Cant we do that using resources routes? it may includes nearly 30 routes line for optional parameters to provide in routes file. Any better work around? I have 30 routes with and without subject_id. so instead of making 60 routes of lines. I want to do work using minimal lines of code. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
  path = if params[:subject_id].present?
          new_teacher_subject_lesson_plan_video_path(@teacher, @subject, @lesson_plan)
        else
          new_teacher_lesson_plan_video_path(@teacher, @lesson_plan)
        end
%>
```

and then

```
<%= link_to '+ New Video', path, remote: true, class: "btn btn-info plans-items-btn" %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, it does the job but can't we optionally add parameters in paths or is it has any limitations with not possible sort of thing?

Comment: well, when your `subject_var` is nil, you will be sending something like `new_teacher_lesson_plan_video_path(@teacher, nil, @lesson_plan)` and I don't think it will work

Comment: Thanks for input. :)